# How can I work around Photoshop Elements 7's inability to open JPG files from my Android phone?

Tags: jpeg, file-format, error, photoshop-elements

I copied some photographs that I took with my Android phone to my laptop.  When I tried to open them with Photoshop Elements 7.0, I received the following error message:

> Could not complete your request because reading spatial lossless jpeg
>   files is not implemented.

Is there a workaround for Photoshop Elements 7.0?  If I upgraded to the latest version  would it work then?

This question was [previously asked](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/962929) at the Adobe forums with no responses currently.

Comment: Try opening them with something else, like Irfanview, then saving as a regular jpeg, then opening in elements

Comment: Another term for this is Jpeg2000 - so search for that, you might find a plugin that way.

Comment: @ChrisF - So some Andorid phones shoot in JPEG200 by default?

Comment: @dpollitt - no idea :) I was searching for the error message to see what was out there and JPEG2000 was mentioned on a couple of the pages.

Comment: Okay.  I *think* I figured out what's wrong.  Under Settings->Location & Security->Data encryption I have checked "Storage encryption", so files on my SD card are encrypted.  My issue now is that I don't know how to *decrypt* them.  If I uncheck the box, it says that future files will be decrypted, but existing files will remain encrypted (including the photographs in question).  Does anyone know how to decrypt my existing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I set up my phone to encrypt my SD card and when I pulled files to my PC, they came off still encrypted.  A [fuller discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20282/how-do-i-decrypt-files-on-my-sd-card-that-i-encrypted-using-the-settings) of this issue can be found on [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find the exact breakdown of what your version of Photoshop Elements supports, but I would guess the [Photoshop Elements 5.0 document here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/330/330350.html#products) is very similar to Photoshop Elements 7.0 that you have. [This document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PhotoshopElements/7.0_Win/WSD349A731-7AFE-45f8-A4DA-7036ACAB6BE2.html) might help as well.

Essentially, the reason that you are probably seeing that error message is because you are trying to open a file that is not a (.jpg, .jpeg, .jpe, .jfif) standard JPEG extension, OR the file is JPEG but it is corrupt.

I would look into how you are creating the photos. Are you using the standard camera application or have you edited the file in some way on the phone. Potentially the software on the phone that is used for editing is saving the file in a format that is not compatible with Elements.

Other workarounds would be to open up the file in another editor such as Irfanview or XnView and make sure they can read it, if so, resave the files(with a new name) and the correct .jpg extension.

The files could also have a colorspace that is undefined or not recognized by Elements. I would look at the EXIF of the file and see if a colorspace is defined and what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).
It supports over 100 formats, including jpeg2000